# How do I fix column values that are missing in a flat file generated by SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have a flat file destination that exports data to .CSV file.

While doing data validation, I noticed that some rows are missing the values for the field `Remarks`.

The issue that I am facing is that not all the rows are missing the values but only some of them are missing it.

#### Flat file connection manager settings:

- Column data type is set to **`DT_STR`** with length **`200`**.
- Text qualifier is **`"`**
- Header Row Delimiter is **`{CR}{LF}`**

Here are some sample values that exported correctly:

```
Multiple repairs # 20021089
```

Here are few rows that seem to have issues:

```
1. #20026982-exterior debirs and demo with permits
2. ID # 20005495 hearing
```

Comment: Simple terms, lets say there is tblA with ColumnA has 10 rows. Some values are missing or shows Blank but rest of values show fine. Now about Data Flow task structure i'm not sure what you're looking for Data flow task has OLE DB Source > Flat File destination. I checked everywhere and found DT_String with Length 200. ColumnA data structure: ColumnDelimiter: Comma{,}, ColumnType: Delimited. Data Type:string [DT_String] OutputColumnWidth: 200, TextQualified: True. Not sure whats else you need.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. For somereason csv file wraps the whole text. You need to manually go into column/value and Hit F2 to see the data/value. There is nothing wrong with process or any data type. As i said earlier it's DT_String with Width 200 everywhere. Thx for trying!!